# How do I export data frame to .csv file created by read_bulk function in R?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I would like help on how to export the data frame created by merging .csv files using read bulk package in R. I have 9 .csv files with data that I merged using read_bulk in R. I tried to create an empty data frame first and then populate it with the merged data. My plan was then to export the data frame to a .csv file. This was unsuccessful. I got stuck on populating the empty data frame. Is there a better approach or edit I can make to the code I am using? Here is the code:

```
>data1=data.frame(Row=numeric(),Title=character(),Color=character(),Value=numeric(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

>read_bulk(directory=directory, data=data1)
```

Data is read from the .csv files and displays correctly on my R Console

```
>data1

[1] Row Title Color Value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: To clarify, the directory I used is correct. I did not post the exact directory as it contains sensitive information.

Comment: Does your directory have files other than csv?

Answer (score 0):

ensure your directory is set to where your CSV files are.
This seemed to work for me - the combined dataframe is stored as `data1`

```
data1<-read_bulk(directory = getwd(),subdirectories = F,extension = ".csv",data = NULL)
```

the you can write your merged data to a combinded csv file

```
write.csv(data1,"bulk.csv",row.names = F,na="")
```